# GKE Inter cluster access to a service does not work consistently changing between nodes and podip based on cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I have the following GKE regional clusters in the same region say us-east1 but each in a different network.

- Cluster-A is running 1.18.18-gke.1100 k8s version (master and worker nodes)
- Cluster-B is running 1.18.18-gke.1100 k8s version (master and worker nodes)
- Cluster-C is running 1.18.18-gke.1100 k8s version master and 1.17-1100 worker nodes k8s version

I have deployed the same kubernetes services on Cluster-B and Cluster-C and exposed a NodePort. I have created VPC Peering between Cluster A and Cluster B, similarly between Cluster-A and Cluster-C.

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)       
serviceb      NodePort    10.2xx.xxx.xx   <none>        8100:31000/TCP

NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)       
servicec      NodePort    10.3x.xxx.xx    <none>        8100:31000/TCP
```

There is a firewall that allows the node internal IP as well as the pod range IP of Cluster-A to reach the service port of Cluster-B 
Similarly there is a firewall that allows the node internal IP as well as the pod range IP of Cluster-AA to reach the service port of Cluster-C

My solution requires one pod on Cluster-A to connect to the above mentioned services on Cluster-B and also the one on Cluster-C

I have an fqdn which maps **myserviceb.x.com** to the Internal Node IP of pod associated to serviceb. Similarly another fqdn that maps **myservicec.x.com** to the Internal Node IP of pod associated to the servicec

The connectivity was fine till a few weeks back (when cluster-A nodes were on k8s version 1.11), when I upgraded it to 1.18 and hence the service restarted, it is unable to reach the cluster-B. This could be purely coincidental but a variable I am considering.

So for my test, I ran a tcpdump on the node of Cluster-A, while executing a curl command from within the test pod - I am noticing that 
`curl https://myserviceb.x.com`   sends the request from the pod ip range (please note that I have also added this range into the firewall to accept connections).

```
Rebuilt URL to: https://myserviceb.x.com:31000/
   Trying 172.xx.x.20...
TCP_NODELAY set
connect to 172.xx.x.20 port 31000 failed: Connection timed out
```

`curl https://myservicec.x.com`   sends the request from the NODE ip range and works

Any inputs would be appreciated. I do not have any network policy in any of these clusters. VPC-native traffic routing is disabled on all the three clusters.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately